# Confidence Bands for Quantile Regression

Tags: quantile-regression

Can anyone suggest a way to construct confidence bands on a particular quantile regression line? I am working with the quantreg package in R.

Comment: There is no such option available AFAIK, unless you are willing to hack your way to a result.

Comment: You may want to ask this question on stackoverflow instead. With the quantreg function call `summary()` around your `rq` object and it should give you upper and lower bands.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will answer my own question for the record if I figure it out and get no other responses.

Answer (score 0):

The function predict.rq is analogous in use and meaning to predict.lm (both can be called by simply using predict). I could not get this to return a useful result using the default fitted values (it returns a vector instead of a matrix). My workaround was to define a newdata dataframe consisting of the fitted values and specifying that in the call to predict.rq.

Answer (score 0):

To mimic the behavior of `predict.lm()` with default `newdata` one can use:

```
predict(mf, newdata = data.frame(x = mf$x, y = fitted(mf)), interval = "confidence")
```

assuming `mf` is the value returned by `rq()`, i.e., the fitted model object, and that the response variable was called `y` and the independent variable `x` in the data used to fit `mf`.